# I can copy file but can not move it from my Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, move

I can copy file but can not move it on my Mac Terminal.

I want to execute following command:

```
mv /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/DATA.xlsx /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/inprogress/
```

And I get following error:

```
mv: rename /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/DATA_21940000.xlsx to /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/inprogress/DATA_21940000.xlsx: Permission denied
```

However, if I use `Finder`, I can move it. But I want to do this from Terminal.

But, I am able to `copy`:

```
cp /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/DATA.xlsx /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/inprogress/
```

Wondering what is that I am doing wrong!?

Below is the `ls -ltr` output:

```
gfss-apac-ipt2:21940000 admin$ pwd
/apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000

gfss-apac-ipt2:21940000 admin$ ls -ltr
total 384
-rw-r--r--@ 1 alokur  wheel  193385 Nov 22 12:09 DATA_21940000.xlsx
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 admin   wheel      68 Nov 22 13:08 inprogress
```

P.S.: Move does not work even when I do `chmod 777 inprogress`; and I get same error.

I asked this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406189/i-can-copy-file-but-can-not-move-it-from-my-mac-terminal), but no luck so far.

Comment: Try `sudo mv /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/DATA.xlsx /apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000/inprogress/`

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, this works but it asks password. I have plan to run this statement from shell script. So do not want to enter password. Moreover, wondering how I am able to copy without sudo though!

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**:

I had to delete the folder `/apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/21940000` and recreate it.
Then I `cd` to `/apps/gfss/ipt/files/R2R/Japan_WHT/` and gave permission to `21940000` directory using `chmod -R 777 21940000/`

I think there was some hidden directory inside `21940000` created by some other user and hence I was unable to do `chmod` before.

Thanks to Ab Sin for his [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406196/167002) which gave me some directions to investigate.